# port is listening in server but unable to telnet ( Django with Apache )

Tags: python, django, apache, sockets, networking

I have developed a Django application which I wish to deploy on apache2.4 server. I have configured mod_wsgi and stuff on a system, which is going to be my server and localhost:8081 (apache's port) is working properly on the server system. I am in a corporate environment. When I wish to access the application from another system, I am unable to access the page.(The server and client are in the same network, both using LAN)

Observations:

- 8081 port is listening on my server system
  (Proto: TCP, Local Address: 0.0.0.0:8081, Foreign Address: Computername:0, State: LISTENING)
- I am unable to telnet to server ip on port 8081
  (Connecting To 10.176.241.35...Could not open connection to the host, on port 8081: Connect failed)
- Able to ping server IP (**EDIT**)
- I have JDeveloper installed in my server system and I am able to access
  the homepage of WebLogic server from another system though.
- Site can't be reached, took too long to respond error while trying to
  access the page from client system

What all I have done so far:

- Followed the exact steps mentioned in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) for configuring apache with django
- Turned off firewall in both client and server systems
- Add inbound and outbound exception rules in Advcanced firewall
  settings in both client and server systems

I am unable to know the root cause of this problem and I have been working on this for a week and a half. I do not have much knowledge in networking and I am badly in need of some help. Sorry if the question is too naive.

Comment: Check if `ping` works. Check if you can connect to server from server itself. It could be routing or firewall problem.

Comment: ping is working fine. What do you mean by connecting server from server itself? (I am able to ping server from server itself, and i am able to access homepage of my application with server ip on server system. i.e, http://serverip:8081/home is working on server. @Rohan

Comment: OK, so your network is notwork.  We cannot help you:(

Comment: what do you mean by network is not working? @MartinJames